# how to make latexmk the default compiler in texstudio?

Tags: perl, latexmk, texstudio

i recently started to compile my documents in texstudio, and there was an issue adding the literature. i found out that latexmk works best with literature to compile them. so, in order to make latexmk works, a perl script must be imported, i installed perl 5 on windows 11, and when i try to compile with latexmk, texstudio throws this error:

```
Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method Win32::GetACP() is deprecated at path/MiKTeX/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl line 143.
```

Trouble finding and setting code pages used by Windows: Can't locate auto/Win32/GetACP.al in @INC (@INC contains: path/MiKTeX/scripts/latexmk/ C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at path/MiKTeX/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl line 143 ILL CONTINUE WITH UTF-8.

Comment: What do you get for `perl -MWin32 -E"say $^X; say Win32::GetACP()"`?

Comment: so i gave this to the command prompt and returned the follwoing:

Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method Win32::GetACP() is deprecated at -e line 1.
Can't locate auto/Win32/GetACP.al in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at -e line 1

Comment: Something's wrong with your installation of the module. Reinstall it.